# Power Apps display mode all conditions must apply to enable drop down

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

I am using below formula to enable/disable drop down. Formula appears to be correct but only works on the first condition.

I need all conditions to apply to enable dropdown. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
If(Dropdown1_3.Selected.Value = "OK"|| Dropdown1_4.Selected.Value = "OK"|| Dropdown1_5.Selected.Value = "OK",  DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable drop down only when all conditions met, use below formula:

```
If(
    Dropdown1_3.Selected.Value = "OK" &&
    Dropdown1_4.Selected.Value = "OK" &&
    Dropdown1_5.Selected.Value = "OK",
    DisplayMode.Edit,
    DisplayMode.Disabled
)
```

**OR**:

```
If(
    And(
        Dropdown1_3.Selected.Value = "OK",
        Dropdown1_4.Selected.Value = "OK",
        Dropdown1_5.Selected.Value = "OK"
    ),
    DisplayMode.Edit,
    DisplayMode.Disabled
)
```

Comment: Ganesh, this is magic! 
Thank you very much!